# Solutions to a mutable MKPolyline?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, swift

I am doing an app which needs a path overlay to be constantly adding points to its path. I think it is pretty cumbersome to be replacing the old MKPolyline with the new one with just one additional point. Is there any alternatives other than subclassing MKOverlay?

Comment: I would extremely appreciate any answers or comments.